# How do I prevent the browser from going to another page after submitting?

Tags: javascript, form-submit

I have a form which user enters data and upload a picture, when user clicks submit, the browser would go to a "confirmation page(its actually blank)", I'd rather have a pop-up confirmation message that when user clicks ok it refreshes the page.

Any ideas?

some details:
first, the user enters data in the textfields and selects a file to upload

when  user clicks "submit button", a confirmation page pops up, user can click "OK" or "Cancel"

if use clicks "OK", servlet is called to handle the form data including the file user wants to upload, if form submit is successful then a "success" pop up

mine seems to go to the blank confirmation page every time, no success pop up

Comment: You can do this with JavaScript.  Have the form action be JavaScript code that pops up the alert box to confirm submission then redirects to the same URL you are on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you set the `action` attribute of the form to empty e.g

```
<form action="">
```

the form will submit to the same page.

You can optionally retrieve the value in the form elements without actually submitting the form, you then process it and display your confirmation message then refresh or go to another page.

Comment: this sounds good, honestly i did not know that i can set action="", ill try it out thanks!!!

Comment: hey can you explain a bit more about retrieving value without actually submitting the form?

Comment: you can use "document.form_name.username.value". It would return the value entered in a form element (type='text') with name = 'username'. Remember to give your form a name. Jquery makes javascript a lot easier.

Comment: i actually just decided to set target='ifram' where the iframe is not visible lols, seems to work fine i guess =/

Answer (score 2):

You would submit via ajax instead of via a form submission.  After the ajax call completes, you can then do anything you want in the page (show a popup) and then go to another page.

Comment: @JoeChen - It is unclear to me exactly how you want it to work.  Please detail the exact order you want the steps in.  Include all of the following steps: user enters data, data gets validated, user gets prompted for confirmation, form gets submitted to server and then describe what is supposed to be displayed when done.  Also, can you use a library like jQuery or does it have to be plain javascript?

Comment: to be more specific, you know when you upload a file and click submit, it usually goes to another webpage, i want it to refresh the page rather than going to another webpage..